# How to fix this EF query? And log sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have this code

```
var result = _context.ComponentHistory
                     .OrderBy(x => x.ActionDate)
                     .Where(x => x.ComponentId == componentID)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.ComponentLocationId)
                     .Select(x => x.First())
                     .Select(x => new ResultModel { });

var query = result.ToQueryString();

var resultModel = result.ToList();

return Ok(resultModel);
```

And I get an exception

> .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I want to order, group elements in table and take first element from each group. Log this SQL

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: you may try using anonymous type i.e `.Select(x => new { label = x.First() })`
Also last select with `ResultModel` will probably fail as well so you should move it after the collection is materialized (`ToList()`)

Comment: Have you tried changing the First() to FirstOrDefault()? I heard First() may cause error in EFCore.

Answer (score 0):

Changing First to FirstOrDefault is the way to go:

```
var result = _context.ComponentHistory
                 .OrderBy(x => x.ActionDate)
                 .Where(x => x.ComponentId == componentID)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.ComponentLocationId)
                 .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                 .Select(x => new ResultModel { });
```

as to logging queries it is best to implement that globally so you do not have to think about it ever again so depending on version of EF you are using
[logging in EF core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) or [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)